# Facebook Auth Dialog Preview is deifferent than actual login

Tags: facebook, user-interface

The facebook Auth Dialog preview shows

"the app may, post on your behlaf..."

but when i try to login the option is not present and while a user can login. no posts will be made.

why are they different and how can i get posts on my behalf to the login?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by using the scope parameters requesting the correct permissions.

Comment: There is no real problem – you are just one of the many that have not understood what the settings in the app dashboard are for: They are __only__ for _automatically_ triggered logins (from the app center, and via the now deprecated authenticated referrals). Whenever you trigger login _yourself_ from within your app, you have to specify the permissions there and then via the `scope`parameter.

Comment: Thanks, when using the scope parameter, it works!