# Facebook App Permission

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Auth Dialog Preview is deifferent than actual login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645983/facebook-auth-dialog-preview-is-deifferent-than-actual-login)

I have created a facebook app and give some permission, the **Preview Auth Dialog** look like [image]

The options are not showing on the site, where I am using the application.

[image]

Comment: you have set some permissions in the access url like scope =email for basic info you can add more scope=email,read_insights,read_friendlists,read_stream read this link for more info http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: yes I have added but can not understand why this is not comming when a user access these app ?

Comment: can you show us your code, where you are forming the login url? in code you need to set all the required permissions in `scope` parameter.

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/13187184/1427878

Comment: require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
 $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

Comment: Mr. Broe which parameters I need to pass for read_friendlist

Comment: best tutorial and free code for fb integration http://25labs.com/tutorial-post-to-multiple-facebook-wall-or-timeline-in-one-go-using-graph-api-batch-request/